# Terminal Services Server memory management on .NET applications

Tags: .net, memory-management, citrix, terminal-services

How does Terminal/Citrix-servers manages .NET applications in memory?

Let's say, my application wastes 100MB in memory. If it will be started by 20 users at the same time, will it waste 20 * 100MB or will it be loaded only once and wastes 100MB for all 20 users?

KR
Michael

Comment: It depends on how it does the wasting, but probably the former (ie. 20 x).

Comment: I cannot fathom why Citrix would treat .NET/managed applications any differently than native applications.

Comment: Memory usage is a bit more complicated than that. Some memory is shared. Some memory is non-committed (and doesn't take up any physical memory at all). Why don't you test it and check e.g. VMMap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking you'll be using 20 x 100MB. However you can optimize your .NET apps to use less memory on TS/Citrix servers by using NGEN. The following blog gives a good description:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/morgan/archive/2009/03/07/developing-net-applications-for-deployment-on-terminal-services-or-citrix.aspx